# How to filter a field from a many-to-many relationship but avoid to cache the results of relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  as_many :role_users
  as_many :roles, through: :role_users
end

class RoleUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :user
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :role_users
  has_many :users, through: :role_users
end
```

And i need to find all users who belongs to `passenger` role.

```
> r1 = Role.create(:name ="passenger")
> r2 = Role.create(:name ="driver")
> 
> u1 = User.create(:name ="Bob")
> u2 = User.create(:name ="Tom")
> 
> u1.roles.push r1, r2
> u2.roles.push r1
> 
> passengers = User.includes(:roles).where("roles.name": "passenger")
# To find all users who belongs to `passenger` or `driver` role
# passengers = User.includes(:roles).where("roles.name": %w(passenger, driver))

> passengers[0].roles.size  # This is correct
=> 1
> passengers[1].roles.size  # This is incorrect
=> 1
```

It seems to load from cached results.

To reload the cache, it works.

```
> passengers[1].roles(true).size  # This is correct
=> 2
```

Is there a better way to do this?

---

I found a better way to do this:

```
> passengers = Role.where(:name => "passenger").take.users
> passengers[0].roles.size
=> 1
> passengers[1].roles.size
=> 2
```

But how to find all users who belongs to `passenger` or `driver` role in this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
Role.where("name = ? OR name = ?", 'passenger', 'driver').includes(:users)
```

or

```
Role.joins(:users).where("roles.name = 'passenger'")
```

Comment: But if i want to find the users who belongs to `passenger` or `driver` role, how to do this?

Comment: Add one OR condition. Role.joins(:users).where("roles.name = 'passenger' or roles.name = 'driver'")

Comment: No. I got duplicate roles with your code. And i don't know how to DISTINCT users belong to the roles.

Comment: Yes. If you use join query, it will result one roles per user. To group that, you can use ruby group_by function. Otherwise you can simply use where condition function (first one). Updated the answer. Have a look at it.

Comment: In fact i just want the users belong to the roles instead of the roles.There are duplicate users among `passenger` and `driver` roles, so my code will be `users = roles[0].users | roles[1].users` to distinct users? And thanks for your help :)